# Use Read Lock when Checking/Modifying data in Program

Tags: c#, sql-server, locking

In Database, Suppose when a car is sold, it'll set `IsSold = true` and record the buyer,

and to know if a car has been sold, I use a if to check:

```
var car = GetCarFromDb().Where(car=>car.Id=2);
if(!car.IsSold){
   car.IsSold = true;  car.Buyer = thisUserName;  
   DbSaveChanges();
}
```

And now there're two users do the buy action nearly the same time,

and I imagine the situation below may happen:

[image]

that is the car will be sold two time, which is a problem.

Is it possibly happens when using C# with MSSQL?

if possible, I think the only way to prevent it is give the car data Read Lock and Write Lock during the whole code block like:

```
GiveCarId2ReadLockWriteLock();
var car = GetCarFromDb().Where(car=>car.Id=2);
if(!car.IsSold){
   car.IsSold = true;  car.Buyer = thisUserName;  
   DbSaveChanges();
}
ReleaseCarId2ReadLockWriteLock();
```

so if User1 start to check the car is sold, user2 have to wait until user1 complete setting the car sold, so user2 will always get `IsSold = true`, that is one car will not sold to 2 users repeatedly.

if it's right, then how to practice `GiveCarId2ReadLockWriteLock();` ?

Or is there other way to prevent 2 users buy the same car, when 2 users send the buy request nearly the same time and on different computer/client?

Maybe something like MVC, or use a Repository Pattern, or do some special skill to process one request one time in WebAPI, so that each request can enter onlty when the former request end?

**Update 201710:**

Here's an [Article in Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) discuss it.

Comment: Are you using an ORM like Entity Framework, or direct database connections?

Comment: Entity Framework is ok. I suddnely think if using Entiyframework, maybe I can use a Controller force to process one request one time, until the request is end then the second request can come in, though I don't know the practice detail

Comment: Is this app web or desktop?

Comment: Two users use Client send request to Server, Client can be browser or desktop program, And the Server recieve the request then manipulate Database. And the check sold code in question is in the client

Comment: Or Client directly connect to DataBase is ok too, for Lock, if client directly connect to DB, then the lock code can be written in client, if it's Server manipulate DB, then Lock Code can be written in Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to create read locks - either via the DB or your app - would work, but the solution would be cumbersome & might affect performance for the majority of transactions which would be outside the scenario you're worried about.

I would suggest letting your DB do this via constraints, but normalize your DB schema.

Instead of having 1 **`Cars`** table with columns:

*`CarId`   `IsSold`   `Buyer`   `OtherCarStuff`*

Have 2 tables:

**`Cars`** has:

*`CarId`   `OtherCarStuff`*

**`CarSales`** has:

*`CarId`   `Buyer` `SalesDate`*

`CarId` would be the primary key on both tables(given the info I have)

Then when you try to write to the `CarSales` table & the car has already been sold, you will get a violation of primay key & know it's sold.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i think it's feasible.

Comment: Cool. Normalizing your DB in this way will give you much more flexibility for future maintenance & adding features.